# Color Cell by using the note in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

Whenever I try to use the following script...

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getNote()){
    e.range.setBackground('green');
  }
}
```

I get the following error...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit  @ Code.gs:2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this code from the script editor (by clicking the 'play'-button)?
If so, the error is perfectly normal. An onEdit script is triggered (automatically) if edits take place in the spreadsheet. The script captures that edit (event) and uses that event-object (e) in the script. If you try to run the function from the script-editor no such event is captured (because no edit took place) and hence all properties of that event are undefined.
Be that as it may, the script works as expected :)

Answer (score -1):

To make your code work, use the following:

```
function onEdit(e){

  if(!!e.range.getNote()){
    e.range.setBackground('green');
  }
}
```

Note that adding a note won't trigger the onEdit event - you actually need to change the cell content to make this work.